# Compare multiple set of date periods

Tags: java, datetime, comparison

I have 3 sets of start date and end dates
1st - start date (01/25/2017) and an end date (02/26/2017)
2nd - set of (01/25/2017) and an end date (02/26/2017)
3rd - set (03/25/2017) and an end date (04/26/2017)

I want to write a Java program to compare the 3 sets and give me the two sets which are equal:

```
((01/25/2017) - (02/26/2017))
```

Note that start date and end date comes from two different variables.

Comment: The question is currently off-topic, please post the code you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: Okay, so your question, thus far, simply boils down to solving “how to compare dates”, once you can do that, you just need to repeat the process over you sets

Comment: I rather think the core of the question is “how to design a program to manage and compare date intervals?” However, Stack Overflow is not a design service, so the question (as I understand it) isn’t really suited for this place, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange::equals`

See the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project for the `LocalDateRange` class with its [`equals`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method. This method compares one `LocalDateRange` with another ensuring that the pair of dates are the same.

That class depends on the [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class built into Java 8 and later. That class has been covered many hundreds of times on this site. So search Stack Overflow for further info.

```
LocalDateRange.of(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 26 )      // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
)                                                   // Returns a `LocalDateRange` object.
.equals(
    LocalDateRange.of(
        LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) ,
        LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.APRIL , 26 ) 
    )
)
```

> false

## `ChronoUnit.DAYS::between`

If you meant to compare the number of days elapsed, use `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 26 ) 
)                                                   // Returns a `long` integer primitive.
 == 
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.APRIL , 26 ) 
)
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a custom class (`MyDateSets`)  which holds a set of start and end dates. The class's `equals` method (override the `Object`'s `equals`) specifies the date set equality.

The example code:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
public class CompareDateSets {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // Parse date strings to LocalDate objects
        // Make 3 set sof them - the input
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDate start1 = LocalDate.parse("01/25/2017", parser);
        LocalDate end1 = LocalDate.parse("01/25/2017", parser);
        LocalDate start2 = LocalDate.parse("01/25/2017", parser);
        LocalDate end2 = LocalDate.parse("01/25/2017", parser);
        LocalDate start3 = LocalDate.parse("03/25/2017", parser);
        LocalDate end3 = LocalDate.parse("04/26/2017", parser);
        // Create MyDateSets objects - 3 sets of input
        MyDateSets set1 = new MyDateSets(start1, end1);
        MyDateSets set2 = new MyDateSets(start2, end2);
        MyDateSets set3 = new MyDateSets(start3, end3);
        // Compare each set and print the comparison result
        System.out.println(set1.equals(set2)); // true
        System.out.println(set1.equals(set3));  // false
        System.out.println(set2.equals(set3));  // false
    }
}

/*
 * Custom class has a set of the start and end dates.
 * Overrides Object class's equals method to define
 * the date set's equality.
 */
class MyDateSets {
    private LocalDate start;
    private LocalDate end;
    public MyDateSets(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    public LocalDate getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public LocalDate getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        MyDateSets dates = (MyDateSets) o;
        if ((dates.getStart().equals(start)) &&
                (dates.getEnd().equals(end))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```